# Where can I read Sword Art Online (Novel)?

Tags: sword-art-online

Last year, I watched the first season of Sword Art Online and now I'm watching the second season. I really love the anime, but now I would really like to start reading the light novel.

Does anyone know if it is available legally online?

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: As a reminder, asking for *legal, licensed* releases in English (and possibly other languages) is fine, but *unlicensed* fan translations are illegal in most parts of the world and so we don't deal with them here. I've edited the question to that effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sword_Art_Online_light_novels for the list of translated chapters/volumes and their ISBNs which you can use to find the stores which have them on:

- http://www.isbnsearch.org/
- http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Search-Books/b?node=241582011

Comment: nice references